# How to connect mapinfo 10 with bing map or other mapping service?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

Is there way to connect mapinfo with bing or google map. I have done this with mapinfo 10.5 but could not find it with mapinfo 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for Bing Map is built into 10.5. You can even see the TAB and XML file, which defines the connection, if you look into the tileserver folder in the installation folder.

Comment: Sorry the version was mistaken

Comment: You can see from the TAB file header in 10.5, that it requires 10.5 as a minimum. It would take a lot of work to do it in 10.0 and I have no idea how. Possibly via a WMS proxy or something.

Comment: Is it even legal to use their imagery without paying for the license like ESRI does?

Comment: @MLowry both MapInfo and ESRI have licensed BING imagery - users can use - license is built into the software costs. 9.3 was a separate license - 9.3.1 was built in.

Comment: I believe PBBI is paying for the access somehow on behalf of MapInfo users. I don't know what ESRI does.

Comment: IIRC Bing map access in MapInfo is only free to the user for up  to a year after 10.5's release.

Comment: Well that was a coincidence - the license ran out today.

Comment: Indeed. But it still works in 11.0